# LDAP search query (using or) not returning values

Tags: ldap

I am using the following query in LDAP:

```
ldapsearch -D "uid=test,cn=Users,cn=accounts,dc=earthlinktele,dc=com" -w dsaasddsa -b "cn=accounts,dc=earthlinktele,dc=com" "(&(|(objectcategory=person)(objectClass=account)(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user)(objectClass=userProxy))(|(samaccountname=test)(displayName=test)(userprincipalname=test)(uid=test)))"
```

but it doesn't return any results, although the (uid=test) and (objectClass=posixAccount) are TRUE and they are preceded by the OR operator. To check if the user have a permissionto search LDAP I used the following filter which successfully returned the desired results:

```
(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=test))
```

I also tried using the admin user as "BindDN" which returned the results.

```
ldapsearch -D "uid=admin,cn=Users,cn=accounts,dc=earthlinktele,dc=com" -W -b "cn=accounts,dc=earthlinktele,dc=com" "(&(|(objectcategory=person)(objectClass=account)(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user)(objectClass=userProxy))(|(samaccountname=test)(displayName=test)(userprincipalname=test)(uid=test)))"
```

Why is the first search not working?? do I have to give the "test" user any permissions??

Comment: Do single-quotes around the search filter make any difference? Or a query for just 'uid=test' alone?

Comment: I noticed that the filter has a "non-existing" attributes, when I removed those attributes the search worked, then I added the user to the "admins" group and the search (with the complete filter) worked. I think it's a permission problem, but what is the permission that allows the user to query a non-existing attribute??